# Drawing a Custom Path on a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uibezierpath

I've been programming in Objective C for a couple of weeks now and a function of a little practice iPhone app I'm making is to draw lines over an image. In my view controller's viewDidLoadMethod I initialise a UIPanGestureRecognizer with

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(drawLine:)];
[panGestureRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panGestureRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
panGestureRecognizer = nil;
```

The function that responds to panGestureRecognizer is

```
- (void)drawLine:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {

    CGPoint start = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self.imageView];

    CGPoint shift = [panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self.imageView];

    CGPoint final;
    final.x = start.x + shift.x;
    final.y = start.y + shift.y;

    UIBezierPath *path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];

    [path moveToPoint:start];

    [path addLineToPoint:final];

    [path strokeWithBlendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

}
```

The code executes when I move my finger on the image, but no lines appear. I'm not sure if this means that it is behind the image that is already in imageView, or if it is not being drawn at all. Any help about how to approach this problem would be appreciated, not sure if I'm on the right track. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a valid CGContextRef to draw into because you are not executing this code inside any drawing cycle.

I'd be storing these CGPoints in a couple of variables and calling setNeedsDisplay on a view or layer which is there for drawing within, and then putting your drawing code inside -(void)drawRect: